How can I use structured_output with Azure OpenAI with the openai Python library?
I want to use structured output with Azure OpenAI.
I tried the following code, based on the code given in https://openai.com/index/introducing-structured-outputs-in-the-api/:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from openai import AzureOpenAI

class Step(BaseModel):
    explanation: str
    output: str


class MathResponse(BaseModel):
    steps: list[Step]
    final_answer: str


client = AzureOpenAI(api_key='[redacted]',
                     api_version='2024-05-01-preview',
                     azure_endpoint='[redacted]')

completion = client.beta.chat.completions.parse(
    model="gpt-4omini-2024-07-18-name",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful math tutor."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "solve 8x + 31 = 2"},
    ],
    response_format=MathResponse,
)

message = completion.choices[0].message
if message.parsed:
    print(message.parsed.steps)
    print(message.parsed.final_answer)
else:
    print(message.refusal)

I get the error:
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter: response_format must be one of json_object, text.",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": "response_format",
        "code": "None"
    }
}

How to fix it?
I ran pip install -U openai: I use openai==1.40.1 and Python 3.11.

I also tried https://cookbook.openai.com/examples/structured_outputs_intro using  using Azure+ GPT-4o mini (2024-07-18), it didn't work either, same error message:
from openai import AzureOpenAI

# Replace these variables with your Azure OpenAI endpoint and API key
endpoint = "https://<your-resource-name>.openai.azure.com"
api_key = "<your-api-key>"
deployment_name = "<your-deployment-name>" # Replace with your deployment name
MODEL = deployment_name

# API endpoint for the completion request
api_url = f"{endpoint}/openai/deployments/{deployment_name}/chat/completions?api-version=2024-06-01"


client = AzureOpenAI(api_key='[redacted]',
                     api_version='2024-07-01-preview',
                     azure_endpoint='https://[redacted].openai.azure.com/')

math_tutor_prompt = '''
    You are a helpful math tutor. You will be provided with a math problem,
    and your goal will be to output a step by step solution, along with a final answer.
    For each step, just provide the output as an equation use the explanation field to detail the reasoning.
'''

def get_math_solution(question):
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model=MODEL,
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "system",
            "content": math_tutor_prompt
        },
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": question
        }
    ],
    response_format={
        "type": "json_schema",
        "json_schema": {
            "name": "math_reasoning",
            "schema": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "steps": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "explanation": {"type": "string"},
                                "output": {"type": "string"}
                            },
                            "required": ["explanation", "output"],
                            "additionalProperties": False
                        }
                    },
                    "final_answer": {"type": "string"}
                },
                "required": ["steps", "final_answer"],
                "additionalProperties": False
            },
            "strict": True
        }
    }
    )

    return response.choices[0].message


# Testing with an example question
question = "how can I solve 8x + 7 = -23"

result = get_math_solution(question)

print(result.content)


I ran into the exact same issue yesterday (I was using latest version of OpenAI's Node SDK though). My guess is that this feature is not available for GPT models deployed in Azure just yet because the error is coming from the service side.

@GauravMantri thanks, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-a-new-openai-feature-for-developers-on-azure/ says it is on Azure.

As of now the response format can be only  json_object or text. For custom json schema is not supported in azure open ai. Need to wait for the updates.

Try giving    response_format={ "type": "json_object" },
and system message like  {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful math tutor. and give responses in json"}

@JayashankarGS thank you, but with json_object one cannot provide a JSON schema for GPT to follow, right?

No. We cannot give further schema when the type is  json_object.

I have tried both the type json_object and json_schema providing schema details but no results. alone json_object helps for json formatting as of know.

Using gpt-4o-2024-08-06, which finally got deployed today (2024-09-03) on Azure, made it work. Code example from learn.microsoft.com:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from openai import AzureOpenAI

endpoint = "https://your-azure-openai-endpoint.com"
api_key = "your-azure-openai-key"
deployment_name = 'deployment name' # Replace with your gpt-4o 2024-08-06 deployment name

client = AzureOpenAI(api_key=api_key,
                     api_version='2024-08-01-preview',
                     azure_endpoint=endpoint)

class CalendarEvent(BaseModel):
    name: str
    date: str
    participants: list[str]

completion = client.beta.chat.completions.parse(
    model=deployment_name, # replace with the model deployment name of your gpt-4o 2024-08-06 deployment
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "Extract the event information."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Alice and Bob are going to a science fair on Friday."},
    ],
    response_format=CalendarEvent,
)

event = completion.choices[0].message.parsed

print(event)
print(completion.model_dump_json(indent=2))

output:
name='Science Fair' date='Friday' participants=['Alice', 'Bob']
{
  "id": "chatcmpl-A3XDRVolXpjeAAQIGddswI990weid",
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "stop",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "message": {
        "content": "{\"name\":\"Science Fair\",\"date\":\"Friday\",\"participants\":[\"Alice\",\"Bob\"]}",
        "refusal": null,
        "role": "assistant",
        "function_call": null,
        "tool_calls": [],
        "parsed": {
          "name": "Science Fair",
          "date": "Friday",
          "participants": [
            "Alice",
            "Bob"
          ]
        }
      },
      "content_filter_results": {
        "hate": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "self_harm": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "sexual": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "violence": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "created": 1725406029,
  "model": "gpt-4o-2024-08-06",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "service_tier": null,
  "system_fingerprint": "fp_b2ffeb31ff",
  "usage": {
    "completion_tokens": 17,
    "prompt_tokens": 32,
    "total_tokens": 49
  },
  "prompt_filter_results": [
    {
      "prompt_index": 0,
      "content_filter_results": {
        "hate": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "self_harm": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "sexual": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        },
        "violence": {
          "filtered": false,
          "severity": "safe"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

Tested with Python 3.11.7 and openai==1.43.0.

it's not available yet on Azure, but if you want to see what it's like. you can try this:
it works for all models support function calling.
it's not an ideal solution, I am just going to wait for the actual structured ouputs to be available.
import os
import json
from openai import AzureOpenAI
from pprint import pprint

# Initialize the Azure OpenAI client
client = AzureOpenAI(
    azure_endpoint=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"), 
    api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"),  
    api_version=os.getenv("OpenAI_API_VERSION")
)
deployment_name = os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_ID")

# Initial user message
messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful math tutor. that solve math questions step by step."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "solve 8x + 31 = 2"}
]

# Define the JSON schema for structured output
tools = [
    {
        "type": "function",
        "function": {
            "name": "math_response",
            "description": "help solve math questions step by step following defined format.",
            "parameters": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "steps": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "explanation": {"type": "string"},
                                "output": {"type": "string"}
                            },
                            "required": ["explanation", "output"]
                        }
                    },
                    "final_answer": {"type": "string"}
                },
                "required": ["steps", "final_answer"], 
            }
        }
    }
]

# First API call: Ask the model to use the function
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model=deployment_name,
    messages=messages,
    tools=tools,
    # tool_choice="none",
)

# Process the model's response
response_message = response.choices[0].message

# Handle function calls
if response_message.tool_calls:
    for tool_call in response_message.tool_calls:
        function_args = json.loads(tool_call.function.arguments)

function_args

here is the output
{'steps': [{'explanation': 'Start with the equation 8x + 31 = 2.',
   'output': '8x + 31 = 2'},
  {'explanation': 'Subtract 31 from both sides to isolate the term with x.',
   'output': '8x = 2 - 31'},
  {'explanation': 'Simplify the right side: 2 - 31 = -29.',
   'output': '8x = -29'},
  {'explanation': 'Divide both sides by 8 to solve for x.',
   'output': 'x = -29/8'},
  {'explanation': 'Simplifying -29/8 gives the final answer.',
   'output': 'x = -3.625'}],
 'final_answer': 'x = -3.625'}

